# how to remove the unecessay straight line in the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The data in the array freq below  is not sorted.

Is there any convenient way to remove the the unecessay straight line from left to right in my plot?

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
timepoints=np.loadtxt("timesequence",usecols=(1,),unpack=True,delimiter=",")
t=np.histogram(timepoints,bins=500)[0]
sp = np.fft.fft(t)
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(t.shape[-1],d=0.0005)
print freq
pl.plot(freq*2*np.pi, np.sqrt(sp.real**2+sp.imag**2))
pl.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it, the plot starts at the peak zero point, then works its way to the right, then jumps to the far left and works its way back to the middle. It is NOT a simple left-to-right kind of time-series (in case that's what you think it is).

One workaround is to plot the positive points in 'freq' separately from the negative points in 'freq'. Replace your pl.plot line of code with the following:

```
mask = freq>=0
pl.plot(freq[mask]*2*np.pi, np.sqrt(sp[mask].real**2+sp[mask].imag**2))
pl.plot(freq[~mask]*2*np.pi, np.sqrt(sp[~mask].real**2+sp[~mask].imag**2))
```

ps, You'll need to set the colors so they match.

Comment: no, use `np.freqshift`  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftshift.html that exists exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you all. `np.fft.fftshift` is the direct way,but I do not know the expression of y axis clearly.

Comment: how to nomarlize the plot?

Comment: @questionhang (1/N) * fft(sp) where N = len(t)