# understanding np.fft.fftfreq and np.fft.fftshift

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft

I have a plot of the power spectrum with unnecessary straight lines, as in the stackoverflow topic: [how to remove the unecessay straight line in the plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390778/how-to-remove-the-unecessay-straight-line-in-the-plot)

[image]

They advise to use `np.fft.fftshift(freqs)` to remove the straight lines, but then it changes the shape of my Power spectrum:
[image]

How am I supposed to use this `np.fft.fftshift(freqs)` ? because this does not look correct.

Here is my code:

````
def PS(time_signal):
    ''' Calculate the Power spectrum of a signal in time domain'''
    fft = np.fft.fft(time_signal) / f_sampling
    PS = np.real(fft * np.conjugate(fft))
    return PS

# plot the power spectrum
azimuths = np.arange(0, 360, 50)
colors = np.array(['b', 'red', 'orange', 'greenyellow', 'moccasin', 'pink', 'cyan', 'm'])

# horn 4
plt.figure(figsize = (13,5))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
for i in range(0,len(azimuths)):
    results = total_fct(Fits_azimuth, Fits_I_h4_17GHz, Fits_I_h2_17GHz, azimuths[i])
    plt.plot(np.fft.fftfreq(len(np.fft.fft(results[5])), d = 1/f_sampling),  PS(results[5]), '+',color = colors[i], label = 'az = {}°'.format(azimuths[i]))
#plt.text(0.00, 0.0, 'Horn 4', fontsize=12, color='red')  # Add text to the plot  
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.legend(fontsize = 10, loc = 'lower left')
plt.ylabel(f'Power [$K^2$/Hz]')
plt.title('Power spectrum of horns 4 at 17 GHz for data set 60D ')
plt.grid()

# horn 2
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
for i in range(0,len(azimuths)):
    results = total_fct(Fits_azimuth, Fits_I_h4_17GHz, Fits_I_h2_17GHz, azimuths[i])
    plt.plot(np.fft.fftfreq(len(np.fft.fft(results[6])), d = 1/f_sampling),  PS(results[6]), '-+', color = colors[i], label = 'az = {}°'.format(azimuths[i]))
    plt.legend(loc = 'upper right')
#plt.text(0.0, 0.0, 'Horn 2', fontsize=12, color='red')  # Add text to the plot 
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel(f'Power [$K^2$/Hz]')
plt.title('Power spectrum of horns 2 at 17 GHz for data set 60D ')
plt.legend(fontsize = 10, loc = 'lower left')
plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout() # Adjust layout for better spacing ```
````

Comment: The order of frequencies given by `np.fft.fftfreq` matches the order of frequency components from `np.fft.fft`. So if you shift the frequencies with `np.fft.fftshift(freqs)` you have to do the same with your data (ie. `np.fft.fftshift(PS(results[5]))` for horn 4).

Comment: right thanks a lot!